# Can the VS WebBrowser Control Be made to Emulate MS Edge?

Tags: visual-studio, date, browser, datepicker, microsoft-edge

I have a Web Page that employs a "Date" type `<Input>` control. When using any browser other then IE or the WebBrowser Control supplied in VS this type of control allows the user to select a date via a calendar. Is there a way to configure the WebBrowser control to allow a "Date" input control type work and function like Edge or Chrome on my web pages?

I have ventured into the worlds of CefSharp and WebView2, but this question seems so basic that I feel like it must be possible. I know I have used the Web Browser control for at least 10 years and it's hard to believe it has not been updated for what seems like a basic control. VS sure has this type of control for its forms!.

Answer (score 0):

The `<input>` elements of type="date" will not support IE browser, so, it will not select dates in the WebBrowser control. More detail information, please check input date type [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date).

To selected date in WebBrowser control with IE browser, you could try to use `<input type="text">`, and then using a JQuery DatePicker plugin to select the date on your web page. Finally, using the WebBrowser control to view the web page. By using this method, you could also use the same calendar style.

Please refer to the following date picker sample (using [JQuery UI DatePicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)):

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body> 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p> 
</body>
```

Comment: Khi Lv,

Your suggestion we perfect! Thank you very much